# How to implement my own UI element on Java?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, look-and-feel

The Java SE don't have a iPhone like segment button. So, I would like to create my own segment button using Java. But my question is...how can I do a customized UI instead of using default UI? Any ideas on how to implement it or where can I start? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to use this custom UI on other components too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to implement your own LaF. Here's a decent ["how to"](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/09/12/how-to-write-custom-look-and-feel.html) to get you started.

Happy coding!

Comment: I don't understand the downvote..perhaps I misunderstood the question?

Comment: As far as I understood the question he wants to implement a custom UI *component* and not an entirely new UI L&F.

Comment: @JoachimSauer, Then the question is more deserving of the downvote, not this answer.

Comment: @mre more than best way, instead of customize UI, why to reinvent the wheel +1

Comment: +1, implementing custom components is not trivial to get right, so reading as much as possible before starting is good advice :-) BTW, the second last paragraph has bullets that are directly applicable

Answer (score 0):

The [JIDE Common Layer](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/oss.htm) (Open source/Dual-licensed) contains a toggle button JideToggleButton that can be made to look like this:

[image: JideToggleButton]

Which is not an unreasonable impersonator.